# Как сделать постоянное считывание данных с Энкодера?

Tags: c++, arduino

Не удаётся постоянно считывать значения Энкодера при работе двигателей. Либо считывается только значение, когда я вращаю двигатель вручную, либо работают только двигатели. А нужно чтобы работали двигатели и считывалось значение.

```
#include <iarduino_Encoder_tmr.h>

iarduino_Encoder_tmr enc(11,12);              
#include<iarduino_Bluetooth_HC05.h>
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
int SpeedLeft = 240;
int SpeedRight = 240;
int i = 0; 
int k = 1;
//  Определяем переменную для подсчёта дискретных поворотов энкодера
// Двигатель A
int enA = 9;
int Time = 10;
int Time_Pered = Time*1000;
int in1 = 7;
int in2 = 6;
// Двигатель B
int enB = 10;
int in3 = 5;
int in4 = 4;
String val;

void setup() {

  // инициализируем все пины для управления двигателями как outputs

  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);

Serial.begin(9600);                       //  Инициируем передачу данных в монитор последовательного порта
    enc.begin();                              //  Инициируем работу с энкодером
}


void loop() { 

  int a=enc.read();                         //  Читаем состояние энкодера в переменную a
    if(a){                                    //  Если энкодер зафиксировал поворот, то ...
        i=i+a;   /* i+=a*/                    //  Меняем значение переменной i на 1, т.к. в переменной a находится -1 (при повороте влево), или +1 (при повороте вправо).
        Serial.println(i);                    //  Выводим значение переменной i
     }




  analogWrite(enA, SpeedLeft);
   analogWrite(enB, SpeedRight);

   digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
   delay(Time_Pered);
     digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
     digitalWrite(in4, LOW);



     digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);

 }
```

Comment: Почему мне кажется, что вы не очень аккуратно выдрали этот код из проекта...? Какая-то висячая скобочка в конце.... Что как вызывается и работает не понятно...

Comment: Во время delay (тем более в несколько секунд, как у вас) данные с энкодера не считываются. Лучше сделать через прерывания. Вот тут есть пример: https://tsibrov.blogspot.com/2017/10/blog-post.html

Comment: такие вещи, как delay с задержками больше 1 мс лучше вообще не использовать. Пока тянется delay, все остальное висит, а это обычно непримлемо.